# `looking-back` performance

Tags: regular-expressions, performance, save-excursion

I have some code using `(looking-back … (line-beginning-position))`.  Doc string of `looking-back` states that it's better to avoid this function because of slowness. I'm curious will following approach be faster?

```el
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
  (looking-at regexp stuff))
```

Comment: It will be faster. But this isn't an equivalent code.

Comment: @abo-abo, yep, it is not. But in my case I believe I can introduce `looking-at` version easily. Thank you.

Comment: The biggest performance issue of looking-back is when it has no limit (or a limit that is far away). If you consider `(with-temp-buffer (insert (make-string 10000 ?x)) (looking-back "y"))` You'll see it is very fast. Now change the regexp to `".*y"` instead : it's unbearably slow even though it's clear to the human reader that this can never match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely. You will especially gain if you just want to test `char-before` or search backward for a literal string.  And if you must use `looking-back` then try to use a `LIMIT` argument, if possible.

See Emacs bug #[17284](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17284) for an example.